# Fancybox 3: Setting different cursors for left & right side of the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-3

I have set up the fancybox 3 plugin (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) for a website and am customising its appearance. I have changed the CSS of the arrows which the user can use to slide to the next/previous image so that the area which is clickable to slide to the next image covers 49% of the screen left and right, i.e. the user can always click either on the left or the right side of each image to slide to the next.

Now I would like to set up custom cursors for each side of the slider as well; the right side should show a right pointing arrow, the left side a left pointing arrow. My current issue is that I cannot set the cursor for either side of the slider, only for the clickable area in general. How can I distinguish these two and set up a different slider for each?

Here's the part of the `jquery.fancybox.css` which I have changed as well as a .gif showing the current version of it in action (I have coloured the clickable area green in order to make it more apparent):

```
/* Navigation arrows */

.fancybox-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 49%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  background-color: rgba(137, 255, 139, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99995;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  transition: opacity .25s; 
}

.fancybox-arrow:hover {
  cursor: -webkit-image-set(url(Cursor-Right.png) 1x, url(Cursor-Rightx2.png) 2x), pointer;
}
```

In the .gif you can see the cursor changing to the right pointing arrow, but it is applied to both sides of the slider.

[image]

Comment: did you check the left and right css classes to the arrows fancybox already has. Try using them e.g. `.fancybox-arrow--left {your css here }`. Similarly it has a --right as well

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Posted as answer. Please accept if it helped. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the left and right css classes to the arrows fancybox already has. Try using them e.g. `.fancybox-arrow--left {your css here }`. Similarly it has a --right as well.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding.